# Function returns address of local variable error in my C program

Tags: c, compiler-errors

My compiler comes up with the error as mentioned in the title. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone please explain it to me. It's been a while since I have worked with C.

```
char** answer(char c)
{

// Initial scanf and check
    printf("Please input the character which you want to build your diamond with");
    if (check(c) == true) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not a valid character");
        return NULL; 
    }


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Preprocessing
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//processing declarations

//Number of Rows
int pre_r = (int)c - 65;
int r = ( pre_r * 2 ) + 1; 

//Declare the column of pointers
char *diamond[r];

//Declare the rwo of characters 
// 2D array declared here to save on computation in situations where characters are not valid 
for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
     diamond[i] = (char*)malloc(c * sizeof(char));

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Postprocessing 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return diamond;
free(diamond);  
}
```

Comment: You should also not `free(diamond)` nor should you use `(char *) malloc( ...` or `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @iharob please ellaborate

Comment: your function will return a pointer to diamond (a memory address). free should be called in a function that called the function you showed. Also, the return statement also means exit the function, which means the free statement in your function is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You can't return the address of a variable that is local to the funcion, because it's allocated in the stack frame of the funcion, hence when the function returns it's deallocated along with the function itself.
2. You are using `free()` wrong, you should use `free()` only when you have used `malloc()`, not even on a pointer that you have done arithmetic with but only with a pointer that was returned by one of `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`. And only when you don't need to use the data anymore, or better when you will not dereference the pointer again.

Try this, I hope that above explanation + this code will help you understand

```
char **
answer(char columns)
{
    int rows;
    char **diamond;

    printf("Please input the character which you want to build your diamond with");
    if (check(columns) == true) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not a valid character");
        return NULL;
    }
    rows = 2 * (columns - 'A') + 1;
    diamond = malloc(rows * sizeof(*diamond));
    if (diamond == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* You must check for `NULL' for every `malloc()' */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
        diamond[i] = malloc(columns + 1); /* <- check for `NULL' */
    /*                                ^
     * if this is for a string you need space for the `nul' terminator
     */
    return diamond;
}
```

Also, please use meaningful variable names, and don't forget to call `free()` for every `malloc()` in this code, that's left to you. I am sure you can figure out how.

Comment: I do not have a main function in this context. When can I free it?

Comment: Whenever you don't need to dereference it any more. That depends on the way you call this function. I am going to sleep now, it's late in Venezuela and I have to wake up early. Please feel free to ask anything I will answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

`diamond` is a local array, and you're trying to return that array.  You should instead declare it as a `char **` and malloc space for enough char pointers:

```
char **diamond = malloc(r * sizeof(char *));
```

You won't want to `free` this variable, since the caller will be using it.